# Paths getting mismatched by nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In my deployment auth-service-svc is hosting a application which has keycloak in it. The Ingress definition is this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: awesome-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /auth-svc(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: auth-service-svc
              port:
                number: 80
```

Now when I give the address as ingress-ip/auth-svc/auth/ I get landed to the start page i.e.
[ingress-ip/auth-svc/auth/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yILWx.png)

When I try to click the Administrator console it gives me a 404 error i.e.
[after clicking admin console through ingress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYIWO.png)

Now in this deployment the service is of CLuster IP type so I can only access via Ingress.

But if I change it to Load Balancer and then try to access the service directly then Everything works just as expected. i.e after clicking on Administrator console I redirected to login page i.e. [after clicking admin console without ingress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjbKr.png)

UPDATE 1:
[Output after changing ingress path to /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM6NI.png)

Comment: You need to configure context path in the Keycloak correctly. E.g. `/auth-svc/auth/` in this case. It depends on the used Keycloak version, so check Keycloak doc for your Keycloak version.

Comment: @JanGaraj So I didnt change the context path but removed the /auth-svc from ingress paths and just kept it as / Now When I click the administrator console the output is a html file. Updating the question with this output (UPDATE 1)

Comment: @JanGaraj I tried adding /auth-svc/auth/ in my context path but it isn't working with that too. With this change I keep getting Whitelabel Error page and not even the start page is coming up.